# What is the origin of the PLS1 algorithm given on the PLS Wikipedia page?

Tags: partial-least-squares

The [Wikipedia page for Partial Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression#PLS1) (PLS) gives an algorithm for the method which is uncited and for which I cannot find the source material. It appears to be very much simpler than most if not all other implementations which I have come across.

My questions boil down to:

1. Is the algorithm as stated valid?
2. Where does it originate from?
3. Why is it so much simpler than other implementations?

Comment: Rather than simpler, it looks more complicated than necessary :)

Comment: If you know of a simpler PLS regression algorithm, I'd love to see it...

Comment: Well, in PLS1, given $X$ and $y$, the direction of the first weight vector is simply $X^\top y$, it just needs to be normalized to unit length. Then deflate $X$ to make all columns uncorrelated to the extracted component, and compute the next component in exactly the same way. Repeat.

Comment: But to make your question more answerable, can you cite some source that explains PLS1 algorithm in a way that is familiar to you? I.e. give some example reference in your Q3.

Comment: Aren't you describing PCA there, as opposed to PLS.

Comment: @MattWenham The idea is very very similar.

Comment: To return to this question, all other implementations I have seen involve either a NIPALS or SVD Eigen decomposition at every iteration. How does the above algorithm do without this decomposition, or else where /how does it perform it?

Answer (score 1):

Further research has thrown up [this webpage](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/distPLS/PartialLeastSquares-1.0.3.html) at purdue.edu which links to [source code](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/distPLS/PartialLeastSquares-1.0.3_CodeOnly.html) for various variants of PLS. On the latter page, the `PLS1` method appears to be very similar to the algorithm shown on the [PLS regression Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_least_squares_regression#PLS1).

The purdue.edu implementation cites ["Overview and Recent Advances in Partial Least Squares" by Roman Rosipal and Nicole Kramer, LNCS, 2006](https://doi.org/10.1007/11752790_2) (PDF [here](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~zwp/teach/Reg/overview_pls.pdf) or [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265929153_Overview_and_Some_Aspects_of_Partial_Least_Squares)) as a source.

Comparing the purdue.edu PLS1 function with the Wikipedia algorithm, it appears that the latter is an optimised version of the former, and probably cannot be optimised / simplified any further.

My original question came about because the Wikipedia algorithm has no 'inner loop', which I now understand comes about as a result of it being an algorithm specifically for a single response variable, which allows further significant simplification.

[Rosipal and Kramer](https://doi.org/10.1007/11752790_2) repeatedly cite ["PLS Regression Methods" by A. Höskuldsson, Journal of Chemometrics vol 2: 211-228 (1988)](https://doi.org/10.1002/cem.1180020306) which is another excellent reference. It states that "if ... Y is a one-dimensional vector ... the NIPALS procedure converges in a single iteration".

I also found [this paper](https://imedea.uib-csic.es/master/cambioglobal/Modulo_V_cod101615/Theory/lit_support/analchem.pdf) very useful.

Comment: +1 Glad that you figured it out!

Comment: Well, kinda. The problem with 'PLS' is that there's no One True Version...